# Максимальное/Минимальное количество символов в поле класса

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

У меня есть поле, в котором я хочу сделать кол-во символов (0-1500), есть некая аннотация или что?

```
@Column(length = 1500)
private String text;
```

length - не действует, ввожу 1100 символов - и выходит исключение

```
com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlDataTruncation: Data truncation: Data too long for 
column 'text' at row 1
```